# Facebook's send dialog - "to" parameter ignored

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, send

I have a simple code that ran for months with no problems, creating a Facebook send dialog with Javascript with a specific recipient. Suddenly for no reason at all, the "to" parameter is ignored and no recipients are populated in the dialog frame.
I tried this in [Facebook console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/javascript-console/) with not luck. Any suggestions?

```
<h1>feed</h1>
<p>
</p>

<script>
var publish = {
  method: 'send',
to: '663218863',
  link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
  picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg',
  actions: [
    { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
  ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Send your thoughts about RELL'
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
</script>
```

Comment: This is the first thing I see when I go to the Facebook bug tracker right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/490271574407364/ -

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear i'm not the only one... Its been driving me crazy for hours now. Thanks :)